Disable logging for called Python function
I have got Python code like:
file b:
import logging

from a import A

class B:
   def __init__(self):
       self.__a =A()

   def f(self):
       self.__a.f()
       logging.info("OK")

file c:
from b import B


class C:
   def __init__(self):
       self.__b = B()
  
   def f(self):
       self.__b.f()

I not not want to have the logging if calling f() from class C but all other logging including other object of class B(also used in other threads which maybe called while C.fis running).
I tried:
import logging

from b import B

class C:
   def __init__(self):
       self.__b = B()
  
   def f(self):
       logging.getLogger("picamera2").disabled = True
       logging.getLogger("mypackage.my_module").disabled = True
       self.__b.f()
       logging.getLogger("picamera2").disabled = False      
       logging.getLogger("mypackage.my_module").disabled = False

Which does not disable the logging (here for using library PiCamera 2 and my self-written package using PiCamera 2).
Is there some with environment where inside a can disable logging?

logging.info logs to the root logger, you need to use logging.getLogger() to get the root logger or update f to use a different named logger

It's a little heavy-handed but you can turn off logging temporarily when calling f with logging.disable:
class C:
    # ...

    def f_not_logged(self):
        logging.disable(logging.INFO)
        self._b.f()
        logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)

You could make your own context manager to do nice things like re-enable logging if an uncaught exception gets through like so:
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def disable_logging(loglevel = logging.INFO):
    logging.disable(loglevel)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)

with disable_logging():
    f()


Fine / thanks. I think in my case there is another problem and because of this the log entries are still active: The logs are coming from c++-library: [1:54:39.154534676] [2877]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1183 configuring streams: (0) 1536x864-BGR888 (1) 4608x2592-SBGGR10_CSI2P . Because I cannot find camera.cpp I do not know what this is doing. A with redirect_stdout(io.StringIO()) as f: did not stop output.
